# prevState is undefined in Enzyme test, but defined in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

Seeing an odd issue where `prevState` is undefined in `componentDidUpdate`, but defined when the component is run in the browser.

I set state in the constructor, and there is a check in componentDidUpdate for a value on `prevState`.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { showForm } = this.state;

    if (prevState.showForm && !showForm) {
      return this.input.current.focus();
    }

  }
```

Here is the enzyme test:

```
 it("should call focus on input if form was shown, and now form is open", () => {
    component = mount(<Component {...props} />);
    const prevProps = component.props();
    const prevState = {
      ...component.state(),
      showForm: true
    };
    const focusSpy = sinon.spy(component.instance().input.current, "focus");
    component.instance().componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState);
    expect(focusSpy).to.have.been.called;
  });
```

This approach works - but only because I'm calling `componentDidUpdate` from the enzyme test and passing it `prevState`.
Ideally, I'd like to avoid that - and just have prevState be defined - as it is when the component actually works in the browser.

What are the patterns for handling this?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the initial state you are setting in the constructor of your component and also what your test code looked like when you got the `prevState` undefined error (rather than what it looks like when you are working around that problem).

Comment: this.state = {
  formOpen: false
}

Comment: Do you have two state variables? `formOpen` and `showForm`? Or should `prevState.showForm` in `componentDidUpdate` actually be `prevState.formOpen`?

Comment: great catch  - it should only be one variable - I've updated my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Your test should not be calling `componentDidUpdate` explicitly. Below is a component and test that I have verified that instead just calls `setState` multiple times to trigger the scenario to be tested.

`MyComp.js`

```
import React from "react";

class MyComp extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showForm: false };
    this.input = React.createRef();
  }
  toggleShowForm = () => {
    this.setState({ showForm: !this.state.showForm });
  };
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log(
      "componentDidUpdate prevProps: " +
        JSON.stringify(prevProps) +
        "; prevState: " +
        JSON.stringify(prevState) +
        "; this.state: " +
        JSON.stringify(this.state)
    );
    if (prevState.showForm && !this.state.showForm) {
      console.log("setting focus");
      this.input.current.focus();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <input type="text" ref={this.input} />
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.toggleShowForm}>Toggle showForm</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComp;
```

`MyComp.test.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import MyComp from "./MyComp";
import sinon from "sinon";

it("should call focus on input if showForm goes from true to false", () => {
  const myCompWrapper = mount(<MyComp />);
  console.log("before first setState");
  const focusSpy = sinon.spy(myCompWrapper.instance().input.current, "focus");
  myCompWrapper.instance().setState({ showForm: true });
  expect(focusSpy.called).toEqual(false);
  console.log("before second setState");
  myCompWrapper.instance().setState({ showForm: false });
  expect(focusSpy.called).toEqual(true);
});
```

Here are the console logs produced by this test:

- before first setState
- componentDidUpdate prevProps: {}; prevState: {"showForm":false}; this.state: {"showForm":true}
- before second setState
- componentDidUpdate prevProps: {}; prevState: {"showForm":true}; this.state: {"showForm":false}
- setting focus

Here is a CodeSandbox where you can execute this test:

[image: Edit xvpo9y47pp]

Comment: The test errors inside componentDidUpdate in response to doing what in your test? What are you doing to trigger it?

Comment: You should **not** be calling `component.instance().componentDidUpdate()` directly. You should be calling `component.update()` or one of the other methods that causes Enzyme/React to call `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: I'm aware that's an anti-pattern but it was the only workaround to get prevState defined. This is very odd - I'm thinking this should have a default value.

Comment: @zero_cool I've updated my answer to try to make more clear what I'm trying to convey.

Comment: @zero_cool I agree with Ryan. STOP WRITING BAD TEST CASES.  First you should know why Didupdate should be called, say by setting state , now you should find who set state, say onClick/ custom props so you should be calling  `component.find('input').props().onClick(); component.update().`

Comment: I would love if this approach worked - but for some reason - I'm not able to set the state twice in the same test.

Comment: If you look carefully at my question - you'll see that I say I don't want to invoke the lifecycle, and that I'm using it to illustrate the strange behavior of the test.

Comment: What exact error do you get when you set the state twice?

Comment: @zero_cool I've updated my answer with a working example. You can run the test in the CodeSandbox I provided.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to get rid of instance method completely. With Some Edit in RYANS suggestion so that you can compare

```
it("should call focus on input if form was shown, and now form is open", () => {
    component = mount(<Component {...props} />);
    // Since you want your prevState.formOpen to be true, first get it in that state
    // This will trigger a re-render and componentDidUpdate, 
    // but you don't care about this execution of componentDidUpdate 
    // (though you could verify that "focus" does NOT get called in this case)
    component.setState({formOpen: true});
    // Then set up your spy

    expect(wrapper.find('input:focus').exists()).to.false;
    // You do this by changing the state and letting React do its thing
    // which will include React calling componentDidUpdate -- you should not
    // call it yourself.
    component.setState({formOpen: false});
    expect(wrapper.find('input:focus').exists()).to.true;
});
```

Comment: I would love to write it like this but the test errors if I set the state more than once - which is also very strange.

Comment: can you write your test case here https://codesandbox.io/s/m50o1ok8o9 and send me back new codesandbox url ?